# Geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue of a matrix is the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace.  The algebraic multiplicity is its multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

It is known that *the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue cannot be greater than the algebraic multiplicity*.  This fact can be shown easily using the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of a matrix.

I was wondering if there is a more elementary way to prove this fact, possibly longer but without using the Jordan normal form?  (This is an exercise in [Kreyszig's book on functional analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=nZmpQgAACAAJ&dq=inauthor%3a%22Erwin+Kreyszig%22&hl=en&ei=JYKuTMe1G4KC8gbmzcTABA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw), and given the author's style, I suspect that he did not intend the solution to use Jordan form, because otherwise I guess he would have given a hint about that. But I might be wrong.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need the Jordan form: suppose the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $k$, and let $\gamma=\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_k\}$ be a basis for the corresponding eigenspace. Extend the basis $\gamma$ to a basis $\beta$ for $F^n$, and let $Q$ be the change-of-basis matrix. Then the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $Q^{-1}AQ$ are the same. The upper left $k\times k$ block of $Q^{-1}AQ$ is simply $\lambda I_k$, and, the $(n-k)\times k$ block under it is all zeroes. So the characteristic polynomial of $Q^{-1}AQ$ is a multiple of $(\lambda - t)^k$ hence the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is at least $k$.

Comment: Seems like this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!