# How can these row-equivalent matrices have the same determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove that the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvector is bounded by the algebraic multiplicity. One particular proof of this theorem that I like is contained in the answer by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45742/examples-for-proof-of-geometric-vs-algebraic-multiplicity/45746#45746) Mathematics Stackexchange post. But there is one aspect of this proof that I do not understand, and I would like it if somebody would please explain it to me.

In the proof that I linked to, the author states that $t I-A$ has the same determinant as $C$. It is not obvious to me why this is the case. It certainly is not true in general that row-equivalent matrices $\mathbf A$ & $\mathbf B$ have the same determinant.

***Meta***: Rather than answering my current question here, perhaps it is better to edit the proof in the answer provided in the link.

Comment: It appears that while $tI-A$ and $C$ may not have the same determinant, their determinants differ by a constant multiple, so they are divisible by the same power of $t-\lambda$. This is all that is actually needed for the argument to work.

Comment: Sir. You are absolutely correct.  If you make your comment into an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: Done! (And I’ll make that slight change in Mariano’s answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a slight oversight in the wording of the answer. Although $tI-A$ and $C$ may not have the same determinant, their determinants can differ only by a constant multiple, so they are divisible by the same power of $t-\lambda$. This is all that is actually needed for the argument to work.